# How to use module template to override a specific Views field and send the right variable?

Tags: views, 7, theming, entities

I hope the title is ok. I've seen many discussion here about using custom templates in a module when using views, but i lack a piece of answer : how to use specific variables from an entity in that template ?

Backgound information about my problem : 
I'm making a module 'youtube2drupal', using a custom table 'youtube_video', having some fields (one of them is 'vhash', the video hash in youtube). With this table i create an entity 'ytv'. I added this key to mymodule_entity_info() to use with Views : 'views controller class' => 'EntityDefaultViewsController',
Then to test it i create a view displaying one video with all its informations => everything is ok.

Everything BUT, to display the video, i need a iframe and i cant't use the rewrite of the output for the 'vhash' field i added in the view field.

The code needs to be :

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?php print $vhash; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

In the suggested template for the view, there is one i can use : views-view-field--vhash.tpl.php

I don't want to override any theme : i'd like to have all the code in my module.
So I created this file 'views-view-field--vhash.tpl.php' in my /templates dir in my module.

I looked for solutions to tell Drupal to use it:

First, I've checked this lead, with hook_theme_registry_alter()
https://swsblog.stanford.edu/blog/using-templates-custom-drupal-module

and i tried

```
function youtube2drupal_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  dpm($theme_registry);
  $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'youtube2drupal');
  $theme_registry['views_view_field__vhash']['theme path'] = $module_path . '/templates';
  $theme_registry['views_view_field__vhash']['template'] = 'views-view-field--vhash';
}
```

but the 'views_view_field__vhash' key doesn't exists, so it seems this is not the right solution to register this template.

Then i saw this discussion
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305114/drupal-7-how-to-load-a-template-file-from-a-module#answer-5307126

so i tried

```
function youtube2drupal_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  return array(
    'views_view_field__vhash' => array(
      'variables' => array('vhash' => NULL),
      'template' => 'views-view-field--vhash',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'youtube2drupal') . '/templates'
    )
  );
}
function youtube2drupal_page(){
  // some code to generate $vhash variable : this is where i'm stuck !
  return theme('views_view_field__vhash', array('vhash' => $vhash));
}
```

=> This seems the right way to register correctly the template but i don't know how to set vhash variable in this context :
i want to use something like `$myentity->vhash`.
but i can't use `$myentity = entity_load('ytv', array($entity_id));` because $entity_id is not defined in youtube2drupal_page() context.

Am i on the right track using youtube2drupal_theme() / youtube2drupal_page() to register the 
template for the module ? If so how can i tell Drupal to use the right value of vhash for this entity i created ?

----- Edit -------
I tried the preprocess function :
I changed :

```
function youtube2drupal_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  return array(
    'views_view_field__vhash' => array(
      'template' => 'templates/views-view-field--vhash',
      'file' => 'includes/youtube2drupal.theme.inc',
      'base hook' => 'views-view-field',
    )
  );
}
```

and added in the includes/youtube2drupal.theme.inc :

```
function youtube2drupal_preprocess_views_view_field__vhash(&$variables, $hook) {
  dpm($variables);
  $variables['vhash'] = $variables['view']->result[0]->youtube_video_vhash;
  //sets the right value into $vhash, but only for the first element
}
```

This doesn't "break" the site, but obviously the `$variables['view']->result[0]->youtube_video_vhash;` is valid only for the first element in the list. If i want to display 2 or more videos, the keys for $variables['view']->result should be 1, 2, ...

So, how can i dynamically set this vhash variable with the correct value ? Is it possible that way ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get the value from `row` object instead of `view` object like `$variables['row']`

Comment: I can't vote up for you since i'm new on this Drupal board, but i thumb up ! Using row IS the solution. I should have tried it . But when dpm($variables), the row bloc showed infinite recursion. I just had to dpm($variables['row']); and all is bright now. Thank you

Comment: In any case, i can display what i need thanks to your answer, but just for my education : the way i get it, is it correct ? using mymodule_theme() to register the template hook and then use the hook preprocess function to change the variable ? Thanks anyway

Comment: Yes, It is correct.